# JOIN whole tables vs JOIN tables with less columns (fetched via subquery)

Tags: sql, performance, join

If I were to do a join between two tables, would there be any difference with respect to the fact I joined them as a whole, or I joined them after having extracted only the required columns (making the assumption that each table potentially has many columns)?

As an example, is

```
SELECT tableA.foreignKey, tableB.someValue
FROM tableA JOIN tableB ON tableA.foreignKey=tableB.key
```

any different from

```
SELECT tableA.foreignKey, tableB.someValue 
FROM (SELECT foreignKey FROM tableA) tableA_filtered 
JOIN (SELECT key, someValue FROM tableB) tableB_filtered 
ON tableA_filtered.foreignKey=tableB_filtered.key
```

performace-wise?

Comment: What does the query optimizer tell you?

Comment: @PeterLang I edited the queries in the question to be a bit more formal, and thus make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the first one, since the second one *uses subquery which creates a temporary table* for the result. And actually `(SELECT valueA FROM tableA)` makes no sense at all because you are not aggregating some columns on the table.

Subquery are sometimes evil, *not at all times*. Tt depends upon the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: MS SQL usually optimizes subqueries away, no performance loss then (although first query looks better, is easily maintainable etc). Sure query plans need to compare to get correct answer for particular case.

Comment: @Arvo I totally agree, but I'm not sure what the OP is using..hehe

Comment: I am using oracle, but I think this might be quite a general question any way as maybe most vendors follow the same baseline under the hood -- but this is just an assumption

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that a subquery will always be slow. 
Depending on the amount of data you are processing it could have a big impact.

Reciently i removed a subquery from a large select with alot of joins. 
The SQL was processing about 100,000 rows if not more. 
Removing the very simple sub select improved performance by 50 seconds.
Overall the sql was taking two minutes. So it had a big impact.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the case that the tables have many columns, the second query could be faster. But its important to note that this two querys are not equivalent. The first one displays you all values from A and B, the second one only valueA from A and valueB from B! Anyway its more a theoretical question and hard to answer generally.

In reality I would leave this decisions to the database optimizer. But if you want to really know if there is a way to make it even faster, the only safe way is to measure and compare the runtimes of both querys.

And as a sidenote, the second query will very probable be flattened by the rewrite engine of your DBMS, so its the same as when you would write:

SELECT valueA, valueB FROM A, B WHERE A.valueA = B.valueB;

Comment: I edited the queries so to make them return the same results (however that was not the point of the question)

Comment: In this case, it should be exactly the same. For the first query, the optimizer will push down your select statements. For the second, the rewrite engine will first flatten your query and then the optimizer will do the same!